# How do linear types interact with features that may change the normal control flow?

Tags: control-flow, linear-types, substructural-types

Linear types are quite a powerful feature of type systems that ensure that "linear values" are used *exactly* once.

For example,

```
fn foo():
    let handle = acquire_linear_value()
    // ...
    close(handle)
```

The compiler would force passing `handle` to some function like `close` before the function ends; otherwise, `handle` would *not* have been used!

This seems fine until other features, which may *non*-deterministically alter the usual control flow, are introduced in the language. An example of such a feature would be exceptions. E.g.,

```
fn foo():
    let handle = acquire_linear_value()
    // ...
    bar()      // may throw
    // ...
    close(handle)
```

Assuming that `bar` is a function that may diverge the usual control flow, `handle` would no longer be guaranteed to be used exactly once.

Can both features coexist in the same language? If so, how?

Comment: maybe take a look at this https://borretti.me/article/linear-types-exceptions

Answer (score 6):

## defer blocks

Swift has a `defer` keyword that guarantees a block to run when the scope exits — whether that’s via `return`, an error, or just reaching the closing brace:

```swift
func useFile() throws {
  let handle = open()
  defer {
    close(handle)
  }

  try bar()
  // If bar throws, Swift will catch the error, run the defer block, and then rethrow.

  if checkCondition() {
    return
    // early exit also triggers defer
  }

  baz()
  // reached end of scope normally, defer runs here
}
```

If there are multiple `defer` blocks in the same scope, they run in reverse order of declaration.

In the same vein, languages like C# and JavaScript have try/finally:

```csharp
var handle = open();
try
{
  bar();
}
finally
{
  close(handle);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## A partial solution

A language like Rust would be able to partially accomplis this. Rust does not have exceptions, which are the primary way that the control flow would be diverted; instead, it has `Result`-returning functions, which the typechecker can easily see might lead to the linear type never being used. Rust does, however, have panics; in that case we will just have to assume that whatever the linear type represents will be taken care of by the OS (like if it's a file handle the OS will close it). This is not a perfect solution, however.